# How to fit data to a discrete linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, discrete-data

Say I have a list of real values such as the following:
`[20.4387, 40.5357, 25.0482, 26.6385, 11.6528, 31.0234, 31.4761, 8.7431, 6.9456, 5.5555, 8.3866, 17.3986, 6.1567, 8.6952, 13.3593, 19.3920, 22.6311, 43.7956, 20.7431, 12.4410, 6.1246, 8.2820, 13.7697, 54.6210, 68.0134, 13.9530, 7.2980, 6.4424, 8.2426, 10.6228, 9.9298, 14.1246, 32.8570, 5.1306, 23.0832, 12.0785, 6.4570, 24.4859, 10.2198, 17.4284, 8.2637]` (there are 41 elements in this list, but that's unimportant, and can easily change depending on upstream input).

And the hypothesis I'm working with assumes the given data must fit a discrete linear model of the form: `Y = c·N`, where:

- `Y` is the given data vector, such as that above
- `N` would be a vector of positive integers (0 is allowed)
- `c` is the coefficient I'm trying to determine through minimizing (what I imagine would be) some distance function like when doing regression using least-squares

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is a integer programming problem. And it cannot be solved with the classical "linear regression" algorithms.

Search for "discrete optimization" or "integer programming" instead.

You may want use some Operations research (OR) tools, such as Gurobi, Cplex or open source ones such as GLPK, CBC, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!